# Can you say that 'something is rated lower'?

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to say that

> 'something is rated lower'

? I think you should be able to say that

> 'something was given a lower rate'

but I am not too sure what about the first option. I guess you would need an adverb rather than an adjective but what adverb would that be in such a case - '**lowly**'? Appreciate any help

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can absolutely say that something or someone is **rated lower**. See this headline from the New York Times: "Harvard Rated Asian-American Applicants Lower on Personality Traits, Suit Says" (source from https://www.nytimes.com/2018/06/15/us/harvard-asian-enrollment-applicants.html)

"**Rated lower**" will typically be followed by a description of the quality being rated.

You may also see: "This movie is **lower-rated** than the others."

Both rated lower and lower-rated imply a comparison to something else. For a sentence without that implied comparison, I would expect "low-rated" or "has low ratings." In my experience, "lowly"  is slightly unusual, possibly because of its primary adjectival meaning of "low in status."

Comment: Thanks a lot for both your answer and the link to the article - very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about the "rating" of something (in other words a "grade" or judgment about how it compares to other things in its category), then you would use "rating" instead of "rate" in your second example:

> 'something was given a lower ***rating***'

Your first example sounds fine:

> 'something is rated lower'

"Lower" is, as you say, an *adjective*, but that is what you want in this situation. "To be rated" is a so-called "linking verb" like "to be", "to seem", or "to become". A linking verb links the subject ("something" in this example) to an adjective ("lower") which describes that subject. You can read about this type of sentence in this ["softschools "article](http://www.softschools.com/examples/grammar/predicate_adjectives_examples/84/)  about predicate adjectives.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer as well as the link to the article - very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to talk about rating, you would rather say:

> 'something is rated **lower than** something else'

For instance when talking about a movie:

> 'The last Iron man **was rated lower than** Hunger Games 2, I now understand why!'

Keep in mind *most of the time* it is a comparison so it even if it is grammaticaly correct to say *"Something is rated lower."* It may sounds weird to stop the sentance here without adding another point of comparison.